# How do I restrict a Windows user account's access to the Program Files, Windows, etc folders?

Tags: user-accounts

I need to run a program, but I want to restrict its access to only the folder it runs in.  I do not want it poking around the rest of my system (it reportedly sends an in-depth report of installed software and hardware back to the publisher).

I was hoping to set up a separate account, and run the program "as another user".  However, even as the Administrator, it turns out I cannot change account access to many folders, such as Program Files, etc.  Unlike some folders, I cannot Add the account in the security settings to deny it access.

This account will ONLY be used to run this software from within another account, and is already a user (NOT administrator) account.  It will never be directly logged into, and doesn't need access to 99% of the drive.

1) Is there any way around this restriction on setting account access to the Program Files, etc, Folders?

2)  If not, is there another functional way to restrict a program / exe so that it can only access one or two folder trees -- and nothing else?

(Windows 7 Pro, have not had time with everything else going on to wrangle together a Windows 10 setup that retains full control of updates, blocks telemetry, etc.)

Comment: I myself would run it in a VM if possible.  Here Mr. Nosey program!  Have your own empty playground!

Comment: And if I use a VM, I can "expose" specific folders to the program so that it can modify only the contents of those folders?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand.  With a VM, it doesn't matter.. Install only what you want that program to see in the vm..  the method below is EXACTLY what you asked for.. but I would still use a VM to keep an app from snooping (if possible).

Comment: The program I want to isolate will soon be the only way to update another program, and needs access to the folder tree for that program as installed.  The "updater" has been an option for some time, but is known to scan the entire hard drive, and sends back reports in an encrypted format so we can't see what it's sending off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. You asked for a question, I give the correct answer, but it doesn't work for you, so now you think my answer is incorrect. We cannot provide you with anything else, thus this question should be closed.

Comment: What is the program? What purpose does it serve? If you have to run the program then the question is why?

Answer (score 0):

To counteract ransomware viruses, by default, TRUSTEDINSTALLER is owner of folders in the Program Files folder, and as such, you cannot alter the security settings, even as administrator until you become owner yourself.

And that is exactly how to solve the problem.

Access the properties of the folder inside program files that you want to give permission to.

In the security tab, Press the edit button. At the top, see who the current owner is (most likely trusted installer. Write this down. Change it to Administrator.

Press OK until all dialog windows are closed. Access the properties again. This time, you can modify the security settings.

By default, All Users have read access to the folder, so make sure your new user is not a member of the All Users group, to prevent it being able to access other files. Now add this specific user to the group and give it read and/or write access to the specific folder.

Once done, change the owner back to what it was before to restore security (this is why you have to write down the name).

And that should do it.

Now, keep in mind that the new user only has access to this folder, but other users on the system will have more access. If you want to make sure everyone uses this new user to start the program, you will have to alter the security settings even further.

To begin, go to advanced, and check "disable inheretence" and press apply. A popup comes up asking if you want to copy or delete the rights. Press Copy, and hit ok enough times until you get to the main security settings dialog and press edit there.

Remove everything until you only have SYSTEM, Administrators and your new user in the group, where SYSTEM and Administrators have full control, and your new user either has read or read/write rights.

If any non-admin wants to run the program, they get an error unless they run the program as the new user. You can simply say: yeah, that does not work, you have to login as that user, discouraging people to be logged in with a user that has more rights.

Comment: I'll dig into that extra step.  Thank you.  I think the part of what I was missing was the step of removing the specific user account from the groups that have default access to Program Files, etc.

Comment: Changing the owner, blocking the "limited" account's access to the folder, and then changing the owner back to the TrustedInstaller seems to be working.  I tried running an exe inside the Program Files tree as the "limited" account, and got a "permissions" message, but just running it as my own account it worked normally.

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately.  The program errors out if it can't gain access outside the folders it actually needs to work in to do the update -- almost as if it's designed to fail if it can't poke around.

Comment: Then you need to expand its rights. Given that the program says it can't access other folders says it works exactly as intended. Its just not the outcome you are after. So technically this answer is correct.